# I am trying to deploy my ruby on rails app to heroku and it deploys properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redis

However when I look at the website I get:

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
```

These are my logs from Heroku:

2016-12-13T04:13:24.541263+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-12-13T04:13:24.540784 #4] FATAL -- : [70c87081-1717-44c4-8e2f-0615224ea231]
2016-12-13T04:13:24.541264+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-12-13T04:13:24.540872 #4] FATAL -- : [70c87081-1717-44c4-8e2f-0615224ea231] NoMethodError (undefined method `hset' for nil:NilClass):
2016-12-13T04:13:24.541265+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-12-13T04:13:24.540923 #4] FATAL -- : [70c87081-1717-44c4-8e2f-0615224ea231]

2016-12-13T04:13:24.541265+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-12-13T04:13:24.540971 #4] FATAL -- : [70c87081-1717-44c4-8e2f-0615224ea231] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/realtime-0.1.0/lib/realtime/realtime_controller.rb:64:in`store_realtime_session_redis'

I also have this in my application controller which I suspect is what is causing my issue...anyone have any idea how I can define this from an envirment variable?

def realtime_server_url
    # point this to your node.js-socket.io-redis/zmq realtime server (you can set this later)
    return 'https://steemstars-tadasu85.c9users.io:8082'
  end

Please any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: NoMethodError (undefined method hset' for nil:NilClass). This here. Probably the cause of your app throwing the error.

Comment: any idea what could cause that issue, i have grepped that error and it looks like it is related to my realtime server....possibly because I have not included my realtime server in my procfile? how can I go about doing that? this is the applications repo here https://github.com/steem-third-party/STEEMSTARS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to configure Redis in your redis.rb config file:

```
Redis::Settings.configure do |config|
  config.connection = $redis
end
```

Comment: I am fairly confident I have that set correctly as shown on my comment below.

Comment: You where correct turn out I was not defining my redis global require 'redis'
# config/initializers/redis.rb
location = ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"] || 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0'
uri = URI.parse(location)
$redis = Redis.new(:url => uri)

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure Redis on your heroku server.

Read guidelines from official site: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-redis

Comment: This is what I have in my redis.rb right now require 'redis'
# config/initializers/redis.rb

uri = URI.parse(ENV.fetch("REDISTOGO_URL", "redis://localhost:6379/"))
REDIS = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password) Is this not correct?

Comment: I have changed my redis config to look like this but am still getting the exact same errorrequire 'redis'
# config/initializers/redis.rb
uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"])
REDIS = Redis.new(:url => uri)